# How to get images from over webscope using PHP?

Tags: php, html, image, apache

How can i display an image on my webpage which i located above webscope? The image is located at **/home/image.jpg** and the website is located at **/home/www/example.com/index.php** which refers to **http://example.com/**.

I have tried this code to retrieve the image, but it does not work :(

```
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    readfile( realpath( "/home/image.jpg" ));
```

And I have tried this version too:

```
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( realpath('../../image.jpg'));

    // OUTPUT IMAGE AND FREE MEMORY
    imagejpeg($image);  
    imagedestroy($image);
```

When I try to read the file with this code:

```
    fopen( realpath( "../.." ) . '/image.jpg', 'r+' );
```

It returns this error

```
    Warning: fopen(/home/image.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/example.com/image.php on line 4
```

Can anyone please help me? I am getting desperate!!!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try  ../../image.jpg  ?

Comment: Yes... Does not work either :(

Comment: get rid of all that garbage - realpath and .. stuff. Why can't you use just plain and simple path as you write it? The error message says there is no such file. Check it's path again. Note that on unix systems filenames are case sensitive.

Comment: I have deleted realpath. The reason why i used it what because another person told me to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet it's a permissions problem: The user your script is running under is likely not to be allowed to access files in `/home`.

Remove the `content-type` header, and turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`: PHP will tell you why it can't access the file.

If that is the problem, you'd do better to store the images elsewhere, though, and give that directory the necessary rights.

As a side note, there is no need to create and destroy an image as you do in your example (unless you want this explicitly, e.g. to remove ID3 and other metadata). A simple [`fpasshtru()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) will do.

```
$name = '/path/to/image';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

Comment: Do not bet. Nor guess. Predict and fortune tell as well. Read an error message and be sure.

Comment: It says the image does not exist, but i dont understand that... I can see it through my ftp program lol

Comment: @Mathias you are aware that the FTP program's root is not necessarily the system's absolute path?

Comment: Yes, but that shouldn't matter when i use relative paths in my script right?

Comment: @Mathias not really, but it makes it harder to determine whether the file actually exists. Can you try a different directory?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The only folders i have access to is **"/"** **"/www"** **"/www/example.com"**. The image is located in "/". I can't put anything in "/www" and "/www/example.com" is the root of my website. I can create a new folder in "/" and put the image in there, but that does not change anything (I have tried). I don't have a lot of options.

Comment: @Mathias maybe you should ask the provider for absolute paths. This is almost certainly a path problem.

Comment: Should i just ask them to give me the path to the "real root" of the webserver and put that right into the code?

Comment: Or maby you know of another way of protecting your images in a proper way?

Comment: @Mathias how is this protecting the images? You are simply passing them through, aren't you?

Comment: No. The idea is that it's only my script which can display the images. You cannot link to them, because they are not in the webscope. The only way you can get access to them i through a php-script which is located on my domain.

Comment: @Mathias but if the script does what you quote above, how is that different from having a direct image link? Are you going to add some additional security?

Comment: Files above webscope can only be accessed through a PHP script located on the server itself. They can't see the image just by typing "http://example.com/directory/image.jpg" because the image is not located in the webscope and must be retrieved through a phpscript located on localhost. And in the php script i have implemented some security check to check if the user is logged in and has permission to see the image :)

Comment: @Mathias I get the part with the script, I just wanted to point out that that in itself is no protection :) Any results from VolkerK's suggestion?

Comment: It don't list any files. In other words, it says that there are no files in the home folder. I really don't get it. I will try to find a company who can fix it for me. But thank you for your help!! It was very nice :-)

Comment: @Mathias no problem. If you want, you can E-Mail me your FTP data so I can take a look. I'm working but I can spare a few minutes.

Comment: Is it possible your FTP account is chrooted and what it sees as `/home` is some entirely other directory of what the webserver sees as its own `/home`? You may very well be FTPing into `/home/users/<youraccount>/home` and your script is looking in the real `/home` instead.

Comment: @Pekka It would be great if you could take a look at it. Where can i find your email adress? I can see your site is under development :)

@Mark B Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @Pekka Haha i totally oversaw that xD An email has been sent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure PHP is allowed to read the file, `fopen($filename, 'r+');` will return FALSE if you can't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this code **fopen( realpath( "../.." ) . '/image.jpg', 'r+' );** and it returns this error **Warning: fopen(/home/image.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/example.com/image.php on line 4**. Is there anything i can do?

Comment: "No such file" is quite unambiguous.

Comment: I have spoken to the company which host my site. They say i can put files in the folder and then retrieve them with a php script. Its a key feature in my application, and i am willing to pay anyone to fix the problem. So if you think you can, just say so

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is how it should be.
No need to look for anything else.

> I have tried this code to retrieve the image, but it does not work :(

When the code doesn't work, a programmer ought to debug it, to find why. And repair.

So, you have to get an error message somehow. Did you look into error_log?

Comment: It says the image does not exist. Thats unfortunately my only clue :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's add more error handling to your script

```
<?php
$path = '/home/image.jpg';

$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
if ( !$fp ) {
  foo($path);
}

if ( !headers_sent() ) {
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  fpassthru($fp);
}

die;
function foo($path) {
  echo 'failed'; flush();

  $out = date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n");
  $out .= " cwd=".getcwd()."\n";
  $out .= " fopen($path) failed\n";
  $dir = dirname($path);
  if ( !is_dir($dir) ) {
    $out .= " $dir is NOT a directory\n";
  }
  else {
    $out .= " $dir contains the following files:\n";
    foreach(glob($dir.'/*') as $fn) {
      $out .= '   '.$fn."\n";
    }
  }
  $out .= "\n\n";

  error_log($out, 3, 'soError.log');
}
```

Keep an eye on the file `soError.log`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code!! I have tried it with different directories and got some interesting results. I just dont have the knowledge to read the errormessages properly :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your webhost has [`open_basedir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) configured, and the /home directory is outside its limits, making the image unreachable by your script.

You can check if it's set by doing `ini_get('open_basedir');` and seeing what's returned.

Comment: open_basedir() is set to "no value". What does that mean?

Comment: Means it's not restricted, so an open_basedir restriction isn't causing this problem.

Comment: Ok :-) Nice to have that option eliminated. One down, lots to go xD Thank you!